# Localise Google MapType names

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to change names of google MapType(s).
Here is example (in Croatian language)
http://www.worldplaces.net/hr/hrv/15/sinj/
So, the names are Karta, Satelit, Hibrid, Teren and Zemlja

I was checking the code but there I can't find anything useful.
Please help for finding solution!

Thanks in advance,
Ile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you listed, the Maps API was requested in the Croation language. The instructions to localize the API are [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html#Localization), and here's a list of [available languages](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1).

If you want to customize the name yourself, one method is to create your own custom map type, like this:

```
var customMap = new GMapType([G_SATELLITE_MAP.getTileLayers()[0]], new GMercatorProjection(20), "My Name", {shortName: "MN"});
map.addMapType(customMap);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
How to request API in certain language?

Comment: solved... 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=abcdefg&hl=hr"